# 32bit TIFF to another format in Python

Tags: python, image-processing, tkinter, tiff

I need to convert a 32 bit TIFF file (or the corresponding int32 array) to another format that Tkinter can display (like gif fe)

How do I do that? Converting the array to int16 or so completely blurs the picture...

Answer (score 2):

[PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) is your best friend.

Comment: could you elaborate a bit? i tried all kinds of conversions and nothing got my anywhere. but i am totally unexperienced when it comes to this, a few pointers which functions i can use would be great!

Comment: I haven't worked with Tiff or Tkinter, but I am guessing you can do something along the lines of [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/521918-pil-and-tkinter-to-display-images/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/), [Image Magick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php), or [GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/)

[GraphicsMagic](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PythonMagick/) and [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php) are command-line programs and have python versions. I use Graphics Magic because it is simple. ImageMagick is almost a command-line version of photoshop...